# JavaScript function() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a strange error Or I'm being dumb and when I search for my error I don't get the answer I need.

I am trying to have some javascript run if a certain key "/" is pressed in a text box.

Here is the Code:

```js
function ClockIn(){
    var kb_press = event.keyCode;
    if(kb_press == 47)
    {
        alert("you are clocking in");
        if(document.ClockIn.status.value === "IN"){
            alert("You Cant Clock in wile you are already Clocked in\n Please try again!")
            document.ClockIn.tx_Barcode.value, document.ClockIn.status.value, document.ClockIn.name.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="ClockIn">
<lable>Type your BarCode <input type="text" name="tx_Barcode" id="tx_Barcode" class="tx_Barcode" onkeypress="ClockIn()" ></lable><br>
<lable>Is your Name? <input type="text" name="name"></lable><br>
<lable>You are currently Signed <input type="text" name="status"></lable><br>
</form>
```

My result is: ClockIn is not a function

Comment: Consider using an event listener instead?

Comment: Also: `<lable>`...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is you've named your "ClockIn" form, so due to age-old quirks in how HTML interacts with JavaScript, the ClockIn form overwrites your global ClockIn function.

Maybe rename the form "ClockInForm"? Better yet, though, you might want to use `document.getElementById("...")` to refer to elements.

Comment: You're right It didn't like being called ClockIn so I changed to InCheck. Thank you